# Checking to see if I'm connected to internet first but my app is giving me an error message

Tags: java, android, database

I'm checking to see if my app first has an internet connection. If it does, I want to create a toast message with it saying "Connected" and execute my task. If it's not connected I want the toast message to say "Not Connected".

Here's my problem, when I'm connected to the internet my app will state "Connected" but the app soon crashes. When my app isn't connected to the internet it will state "Not Connected" (which is great because at least that part if working fine). My question is, how will I get my app not to crash? Below is my syntax and logcat error information. What do you guys think?

```
package com.example.connectexternaldatabase;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView getAllCustomerListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getAllCustomerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.getAllCustomerListView);


        isThisDeviceConnectedToTheInternet();
    }

    public void isThisDeviceConnectedToTheInternet(){

        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(networkInfo !=null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new GetAllCustomerTask().execute(new APIConnector());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


    public void setListAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray){
        getAllCustomerListView.setAdapter(new GetAllCustomerListViewAdapter(jsonArray, MainActivity.this));
    }

    private class GetAllCustomerTask extends AsyncTask<APIConnector, Long, JSONArray>{

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(APIConnector... params) {
            // executed on the background thread
            return params[0].GetAllCustomers();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            setListAdapter(jsonArray);
        }



    }

}
```

Logcat Information

```
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at com.example.connectexternaldatabase.GetAllCustomerListViewAdapter.getView(GetAllCustomerListViewAdapter.java:75)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8314)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8314)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8314)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8314)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8314)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8314)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:841)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1861)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:870)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
01-01 16:51:47.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4633):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

GetAllCustomerListViewAdapter

```
package com.example.connectexternaldatabase;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GetAllCustomerListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private JSONArray dataArray;
    private Activity activity;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public GetAllCustomerListViewAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray, Activity a){
        this.dataArray = jsonArray;
        this.activity = a;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.dataArray.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // set up convert View, if it's null 
        ListCell cell;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_all_customer_list_view_cell, null);
            cell = new ListCell();

            cell.fullName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customer_name);
            cell.color = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customer_favorite_color);
            cell.facebook = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customer_facebook);
            cell.twitter = (TextView) convertView.findViewWithTag(R.id.customer_twitter);
            cell.instagram = (TextView) convertView.findViewWithTag(R.id.customer_instagram);
            cell.mobile = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customer_mobile);

            convertView.setTag(cell);

        } else {
            cell = (ListCell) convertView.getTag();
        }

        try{

            JSONObject jsonObject = this.dataArray.getJSONObject(position);
            cell.fullName.setText(jsonObject.get("name")+" "+jsonObject.getString("last_name"));


            cell.color.setText("Favorite Color: "+jsonObject.getString("fav_color"));
            cell.facebook.setText("Facebook: "+ jsonObject.getString("facebook"));
            cell.twitter.setText("Twitter: "+ jsonObject.getString("twitter"));
            cell.instagram.setText("Instagram: "+ jsonObject.getString("instagram"));

            String mobile = jsonObject.getString("instagram");
            if(mobile.equals("instagram")){
                cell.mobile.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return convertView;
    }

    private class ListCell{
        private TextView fullName;
        private TextView color;
        private TextView facebook;
        private TextView twitter;
        private TextView instagram;
        private ImageView mobile;
    }

}
```

Comment: The crash happens because of `new GetAllCustomerTask().execute(new APIConnector());`. Maybe opening a new activity there?

Comment: at com.example.connectexternaldatabase.GetAllCustomerListViewAdapter.getView(GetAllCustomerListViewAdapter.java:75), Check for any null object.

Comment: show the code of your adapter

Comment: @ligi I've added my syntax above

Comment: @Pietu1998 I've added my syntax above

Comment: show line 75 GetAllCustomerListViewAdapter.java:75

Comment: @ligi `cell.twitter.setText("Twitter: "+ jsonObject.getString("twitter"));` this is line 75. This syntax is the same as the other getString methods in my function. I'm perplexed